# What's the difference between private: & private slots: in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I write a simple ImageViewer app  in Qt5. In examples of framework I saw the same app, for make my program better. And I want to know what's difference between private: & private slots, why I can't put it in just private section, if in this example haven't any connect() function ? [the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xk33.png)

I want to understand what's difference in this case?

Comment: Regarding slots themselves, it's a very Qt-specific thing, that should be explained in great detail in the Qt documentation. So `private slots` is handled by one of the Qt preprocessor programs, it's not a C++ thing. Which is the reason you need `private slots` (or `public slots`).

Comment: Qt uses signal slot mechanism. To deliver it some macros are introduced and  some special tool which generates code for signals and slots including some metadata. Please read Qt documentation for details. This is most important Qt feature so any course about Qt explains this feature.

Comment: In the newer Qt versions (5 included) one can just use function pointer syntax when connecting signals to slots and then the keyword is mostly not needed. The old-style SIGNAL/SLOT macros might be needed when doing sth more complex, e.g. trying to access slots insided a shared object plugin.